# how i can remove Go BuildID= from binary file

Tags: go

is there a way to remove **Go BuildID=value** from go binary file, after I build it.

```
$ go build -ldflags "-s -w" .
```

output hello binary file

```
$ file hello
```

output

```
hello: ELF 64-bit LSB executable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), statically linked, Go BuildID=AXhtNKJoDgAPpm-xK7Ob/WQUqjLjqQcBs6XJONHZF/oUnHbwNyhieOUlsruE4j/7XMKJ0XUJgPWedTUHZbA, stripped
```

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why do you need this?

Comment: @icza only GO do that, other binary files be like that BuildID[sha1]=f341391850cd292687b16cc18a2f1ce09a24522f

Comment: @icza it would be useful to calculate hash on the binary with the buildid removed for lambda deployments with aws-cdk. It uses the hash of the binary to determine if the lambda requires updating. If the source code has not changed then I dont want an update essentially

Answer (score 1):

-ldflags=-buildid=

ref:
https://github.com/golang/go/issues/34186

example:
go build -ldflags="-w -s -buildid=" .